# which is important cache hit rate or cache latency rate for different levels of cache? why?

Tags: caching

As we know there are there level of caches L1, L2, L3. Which characteristic is more important cache hit rate or cache latency rate for each cache as we go from L1 to L3 cache level and why.

Answer (score 2):

Both are important because they depends upon each other. They are directly proportional to each other.

> Latency rate and cache hit rate increase with the size(Level) of cache memory.

`L1` has lesser size than `L2` and `L3` has lesser size than `L3`. Therefore `L1` has smallest size, lowest latency rate and lowest cache hit rate.

**Why cache hit rate increases with cache size?**

More the numbers of `lines` are present in cache memory, more the numbers of `blocks` of data can be held and more the chances of `cache hit`.

**Why latency rate increases with cache size?**

Circuitry become complex and dense with the increase in `lines` in cache memory. Also searching for a specific `line` in cache also increase response time.

**Here is a table of estimated latency rate for cache hit for Core i7 Xeon 5500**

Found at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-manycore-testing-lab/topic/287236

```
    Core i7 Xeon 5500 Series Data Source Latency (approximate)               

local  L1 CACHE hit,                              ~4 cycles (   2.1 -  1.2 ns )
local  L2 CACHE hit,                             ~10 cycles (   5.3 -  3.0 ns )
local  L3 CACHE hit, line unshared               ~40 cycles (  21.4 - 12.0 ns )
local  L3 CACHE hit, shared line in another core ~65 cycles (  34.8 - 19.5 ns )
local  L3 CACHE hit, modified in another core    ~75 cycles (  40.2 - 22.5 ns )

remote L3 CACHE (Ref: Fig.1 [Pg. 5])        ~100-300 cycles ( 160.7 - 30.0 ns )

local  DRAM                                                   ~60 ns
remote DRAM                                                  ~100 ns
```